BigQuery - The bigger query executes while the subquery is throwing an error
I have a a query which filters for an enrollment_year on a student's expenditure data.
select student_id 
from table1 
where enrollment_year = 2003 
group by 1

This query is returning the following error:

Unrecognized name: enrollment_year at [1:100]

The reason being, the column name and the data type is incorrectly mentioned, the right query should have been:
select student_id 
from table1 
where enrol_year = 'Year 2003' 
group by 1

However, when I use the first query as an inner query inside a larger query; the whole query executes and produces a result.
An example:
select grade, count(*)
from `table2`
where student_id in (select student_id 
                     from `table1` 
                     where enrollment_year = 2003 
                     group by 1)
group by 1;

I was expecting the larger query to fail since the inner query is throwing an error.
Not sure why the last query is working without errors.
Thanks.

I too would have expected this to fail.  What would be ideal would be a complete example of a recreate.... for example some SAMPLE data for table1 and table2 so that I could try at my end.  One last thought ... by any chance is there a column in table2 called "enrollment_year"?  If yes, then there is no error.

Thanks. It was because the 'enrollment_year' column existed in table2 as well. @Kolban

ALWAYS put the table name or its alias before ALL columns or expressions you select in your query, even if you think it would be clear from what table they come.

Without additional information about the DB engine or table structures I would assume that the enrollment_year column exists inside table2. Since you didn't specify which table the column is coming from in the sub query the DB system probably just assumed you were referencing the column from table2 seeing as it does not exist in table1.
You can check this other post where a similar question was asked: Query with broken sub-select should result in error but returns rows

Thanks. It was because the 'enrollment_year' column existed in table2 as well.
